# How to read and display images from local directory into a web page using php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display directory folders list on left side of web page and its contents on right side of the page only after clicking the related folder/file, how to achieve this?
I worked on how to get the folder structure from local directory it is working good but i am unable to display the contents after clicking the related file.

```
<ul>
   <li id="li1">
<a href="">
<?php
  $root = 'C:\Users\Public\Pictures';
  $pathLen = strlen($root);
  listFolderFiles($root, 0, strlen($root)); ?>            
</a> 
   </li>
 </ul>

<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8" style="border: 1px solid">
   <img src="" width="100px" height="100px;">
</div>
```

PHP:

```
  <?php 
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo '<li>'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: the images will be on server or on the users local storage?

Comment: Where is the code of listFolderFiles($root, 0, strlen($root)) function ? as function listFolderFiles($dir) accept only one argument and you are passing 3 arguments

Comment: images will be on my local system i.e, on c drive @AmarjitSingh

Comment: listFolderFiles code is above mentioned even placing listFolderFiles($root) is also working fine, how to display all images with in the page when i clicked  on particular folder name? (example pictures)

Answer (score 3):

**Use Base64 Encoded Images**

First, Show your file name like this.

```
<li data-imgpath="C:\Users\Public\Pictures">Image</li>
```

When a user clicks on a file make an ajax request with the image path in it.

```
<script>
$('li').click(function(){
    var image_path = $(this).data('imgpath');
    $.ajax({
        url : "url to a php script to handle image request.",
        method : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        data : {
            image_path : image_path
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $('select your img tag').attr('src', response.image_src);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now create a PHP script to return image data from the image path.

```
<?php
$image_path = $_POST['image_path'];

$image_extension = explode('.', $image_path);

$image_extension = end($image_extension);

$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_path));

$data = ['image_src' => 'data:image/'.$image_extension.';base64,'.$image];

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: I want to display all the sub folders list which are in my C:\Users\Public\Pictures folder and when i click on particular folder name all the images in that folder should display on right side of my web page as this li will display on left side of the page. @Amarjit

Comment: As i am new to ajax I am just trying the above code, getting notice and warning, no data is posting in image_path it is showing null so that file also not getting contents how to resolve it? @Amarjit

Comment: use google chrome's developer tools to see what's coming in ajax response.

Comment: can any one suggest me the solution for my question?

Comment: anyone suggest me how to display all images of folder only when clicked on that folder name dynamically i had multiple folders?